# Could not find schema information for the element 'httpruntime'

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to increase the execution timeout and file upload limit on my asp.net website but when i try to add

```
<httpRuntime
    executionTimeout="110"
    maxRequestLength="4096">
  </httpRuntime>
```

i get the following errors:

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'httpruntime'.
Could not find schema information for the element 'executionTimeout'.
Could not find schema information for the element 'maxRequestLength'.
```

According to this msdn library [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) this is how I'm supposed to do it,so what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<location path="YourUploadPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="{your value here}" 
                     executionTimeout="{your value here}" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

means, `<httpRuntime>` section should be inside `<system.web>` or `<location><system.web>` sections.

Comment: ohh, i was supposed to put that inside <system.web>, thanks it is working now.